# Midori keeps opening a faq

Tags: midori

i have a setup with 3 pi's that all start in fullscreen in midori and all off that works but after some time midori opens a new window with the faq page on it and it blocks the fullscreen

anybody knows what to do?

Answer (score 1):

At a guess you may be pressing the <kbd>F1</kbd> key accidentally *(by something pressing against, or using a faulty keyboard, etc)* causing it to open the FAQ `midori:faq`

You should be able to disable this shortcut by editing this line in `~/.config/midori/accels`:

```
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/Browser/HelpFAQ" "F1")
```

so it is like:

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/Browser/HelpFAQ" "")
```

disabling the shortcut. You need to remove the `;` to uncomment the line so it is read into the configuration, and you can remove (or change) the `F1` bit to remove the association with the F1 key